# Terminal runs svn commands very slowly, how can I speed this up?

Tags: macos, mac, svn

Spending all day in terminal is beginning to get frustrating.

We're working with large CakePHP projects, including a ton of schema files and complex controllers. Whenever I go into a project, and enter svn up, or svn ci my system chokes. It takes a good 15-30 seconds before it returns what revision number I'm on.

I'm running OSX 10.6 on a Macbook Pro.

Any reasoning behind this? Anyway I could fix this speed issue?

Comment: Use [`git`](http://git-scm.com/).

Comment: What if I don't have the option for git?

Comment: Buy a faster machine? `svn` I view as intolerably slow now that I'm used to `git`.

Comment: @Josh, A faster machine would be lovely. :) Seems like there's no other way to speed up svn. Hopefully we could switch to git in the future. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

This is some kind of bug with svn on OS X.

Why I believe this: I'm running FreeBSD as a VM in VirtualBox on my machine (2.8 GHz Core i7, 4G RAM)... I'm checking out from the same repository, using svn+ssh. My native OS (OS X) takes at least twice as long to do any operation.

Try it out. Super strange. Clearly the two operations are using the same network, the same RAM... and since the FreeBSD instance is a VM it should have more overhead and take longer to run... but that doesn't seem to be the case. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

free up your memory- close unwanted programs, or unneccisary proccesses- like dock (yes, you can shut down dock.Finderutill while still running mac osx).

Answer (score 0):

How old is the MBP? Which version of Subversion? Is your subversion repository local or remote?

If it's remote, then the main cause of delay is the network and/or the remote server.

In that case, you might want to upgrade your network equipment or the server that's hosting it.

Comment: First gen Aluminum Macbook Pro. About a year old. SVN is remote. Interesting, I'll have to look into that. Our network is quite fast... shouldn't cause too much of a lag. Maybe it's our server. Thanks!